React Native - Element type is invalid, but changing imports not helping
I saw lots of other questions about this error, and the solution is often a wrong import/export. However, I have been getting this error for a while, and all the imports seem to be correct. How can this problem be fixed?
Error:
Uncaught Error
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Explore`.

Code (following from this tutorial with minor changes):
import { useLocalSearchParams } from "expo-router";

import React from 'react';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

export default function Explore() {
    const params = useLocalSearchParams();

    return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <MapView
            style={{
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%"
            }}

            initialRegion={{
                latitude: 37.78825,
                longitude: -122.4324,
                latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
            }}
        />
    </View>
    );
}

Tried reinstalling dependencies and reimporting MapView (both default and named export).
Notably, removing import MapView from 'react-native-maps' and the MapView element fixed the problem, so the problem is lying somewhere there.
